# Find B such that $\det(B)>0$ but there is no real $A$ with $\exp{(A)}=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

I have proved that $\exp(\text{tr}(A)) = \det (\exp (A))$. An easy corollary is that $\exp (A)$ has positive determinant whenever $A$ is real. Now the question asks us to find a B such that $\det(B)>0$ but there is no real $A$ with $\exp{(A)}=B$. I have no idea how to proceed so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could drop me a hint.

Comment: What about a diagonal matrix? Would it have to have positive entries on the diagonal?

Comment: @GregMartin No as long as the product is positive, but I thought it is not necessary that $\exp(A)$ must have positive entries? Correct me if I misunderstand your hint.

Comment: It's not necessary in general, but diagonal matrices are special....

Comment: @GregMartin But $A$ doesn't have to be diagonal? I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I thought you meant pick a diagonal $B$ with a positive determinant?

Comment: If you pick $B=\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$ you find $A=\exp(B)$ with $B=\pmatrix{0&\pi/2\\-\pi/2&0}$, so don't pick that one!

Comment: Another hint. If $A$ is the exponential of a real matrix, then it's the square of a real matrix. Can you find a positive determinant real matrix with no real square root?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Any idea what matrix should I pick?

Comment: @M.W I do know an example, but you only asked for a hint....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry I sent that message without having seen your hint. I would let you know when I come up with an example.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown there is something wrong in your example. $\cos{\pi/2}\neq -1$. I guess you meant $t=\pi$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry I still couldn't think of an example. I originally thought that the square root of a diagonal matrix must be the matrix with square roots in the diagonal, but with your example of $B$ it doesn't happen to be the case. I'm not sure what properties a matrix must have for it to have a real square root.

Comment: Think: Diagonal with entries $-1$ and $-2$. What are the eigenvalues of its square root?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh that makes so much sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I needed an embarrassing amount of coffee to see the point of Greg's and Lord Shark's hints :-/